# GridSearchCV deprecated iid future warning

Tags: python, deprecation-warning, gridsearchcv

I'm using python GridSearchCV (sklearn v0.20.3) and recently upgraded to v0.22.2. Now my GridSearchCV is producing a future warning:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid={'penalty': ['l1'], 'solver': ['liblinear'], 'tol': [1e-6], 'max_iter': [int(1e6)], 'warm_start': [True], 'C': [cI]}, cv=cv, n_jobs=1, scoring=scoring, refit=False, return_train_score=False, iid=True)

C:\development\python\venv\smote\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py:823: FutureWarning: The parameter 'iid' is deprecated in 0.22 and will be removed in 0.24.
"removed in 0.24.", FutureWarning
```

I couldn't find information about A) why iid is being deprecated? B) What's going to replace it, if any? and C) What's going to be the default behavior, once it *is* depracted?
I'm concerned I might have unexpected behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: did you found any answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see discussion here:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9103

from what I'm gathering: you should remove the parameter, this will change the behaviour but if it changes a lot the new behaviour should be more correct.